Interpretation of Complex Differentiability for Functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$
I understand that any complex-valued function $ f(z) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y) $, where $ z = x + iy $, can be viewed as a function from $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ to $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ by considering $ f(z) $ as the vector-valued function
$$
\mathbf{F}(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix} u(x, y) \\ v(x, y) \end{pmatrix}.
$$
My questions are:

Does complex differentiability imply infinite differentiability for $ \mathbf{F}(x, y) $? In other words, if the vector-valued function $ \mathbf{F}(x, y) $ is once differentiable in the sense of real analysis in a nbd and satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann (CR) equations, i.e.,

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x},
$$
does this imply that $ \mathbf{F}(x, y) $ is infinitely differentiable?

How can we interpret the Taylor series, residue theorem, etc., in this context? When viewing complex functions as functions from $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ to $ \mathbb{R}^2 $, can the classical tools of complex analysis like the Taylor series expansion and the residue theorem be interpreted in terms of real vector calculus when the vector field satisfies CR equations? If so, how?

Any insights or references that clarify these concepts would be greatly appreciated!
P.S.:If a real-valued function $u: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ has partial derivatives, and there exists another function $v: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla u$ is perpendicular to $\nabla v$ at every point, then $u$ and $v$ are infinitely differentiable. This implies that $u + iv$ is analytic in the complex sense and, consequently, $u$ is infinitely differentiable. Isnt this surprising? If so, how can this result be motivated geometrically, and what makes the existence of a function with perpendicular gradient drastically improve the regularity of a function?

The answer to 1 is yes. If $F$ satisfies those conditions then $f$ is entire, so has a power series expansion with infinite radius of convergence, hence the same holds for $F$. Taylor expansions are a very general feature and make sense got maps between any Banach spaces.

What I think is we define differentiability of a function in an interval. And for second question you want to see function from $R^2$ to $R^2$ then it is good time to study multivariable calculus because vector field will be analogous to this.

@LuckyChouhan Thanks for your comment. I haven't seen books mentioning about infinite differentiablity of vector fields when they satisfy CR equations. Do u know of any references which takes this approach and connect real vector fields with the results of complex analysis

@peek-a-boo Thank you for your comment. Any thoughts on residue calculus for vector fields on R^2 satisfying CR equations

@Celestina no no, what I was saying is we represent vector field as $F = P \hat{i} + Q \hat{j}$ so we need 4-dimensional plane to plot this, that's analogy I was talking about :') Yeah, Peek-a-boo's comment was very helpful.

@peek-a-boo If a real-valued function $u: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ has partial derivatives, and there exists another function $v: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla u$ is perpendicular to $\nabla v$ at every point, then $u$ and $v$ are infinitely differentiable. This implies that $u + iv$ is analytic in the complex sense and, consequently, $u$ is infinitely differentiable. Isnt this surprising? If so, how can this result be motivated geometrically, and what makes the existence of a function with perpendicular gradient drastically improve the regularity of a function?

@Celestina Very interesting question. Never thought about it

I don’t think your theorem works as stated; you should assume $u,v$ are differentiable rather than merely partials existing, and also orthogonality alone isn’t enough (e.g look at a bad $u$ and take $v=0$). Anyway, these regularity results aren’t really geometric, atleast I don’t consider them as such. Rather, the Cauchy-Riemann equations are elliptic, and one of the fundamental features of these guys is the a-priori elliptic estimates (in terms of Sobolev spaces); coupled with Sobolev embedding, this essentially gives us the elliptic regularity theorems.

also, regarding your question about residues, I don’t have a nice vector-field interpretation. In fact, often we do things the other way: given a vector field, we often try to go back to the complex setting and leverage the theorems there.
